# What is the Time Complexity of Execute-Ordering Service-Validate transaction processing when using the Kafka algorithm in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What is the overall time complexity of the Execute-Ordering Service-Validate transaction when using the Kafka algorithm under the assumption of a Hyperledger Fabric containing credential-related content? + Please let me know based on when the number of clients is 100 and 50,000.

I want to learn Hyperledger Fabric architecture and algorithm time complexcity.